Boy turns into car and back again...?
I remember ages ago back in the 80's when everything was still cool and Optimus Prime was still voiced by Peter Cullen...
But there was another cartoon which although was somewhat crazy in concept but I was 7, I didn't care! Problem is, I don't recall what this cartoon was called...
The premise was this... Some kid managed to find himself in a laboratory which had some experiment going on with an intelligent car and a laser. The kid gets caught in the beam of the laser and his (wait for it) DNA is merged with the car...
Supposedly, if I recall vaguely a scene which keeps playing in my head, if he gets heated up, he turns into the car, if he cools down he can revert to his human form. There were another boy and girl in the cartoon who were sidekicks...
I think this was done by Ruby and Spears... (I'm reaching here...) Anyone have any idea what I'm referring to? And if so, do you think it may be available on YouTube, providing I can find the title?

Pretty sure it is Turbo Teen(although I haven't watched it)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Teen
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0211171/

Just reading the synopsis on Wikipedia from the link you provided @J0rge, and that's definitely it... Thanks...
For some reason I thought it was "Teen Racer"... No wonder I couldn't find it...
Guess I'll be hunting on Youtube!
